# Is there any website that tells what vegan recipes I can cook with X and Y ingredients?

Tags: veganism, cooking, resources

The internet is full of many recipes collections, with a variety of websites with many different features. Sometimes they let you make searches with a richness of parameters.

Let's say I open my fridge and there are a couple of ingredients I want to use, but I don't know how to use them and I'm looking for suggestions; so is there any website that tells what vegan recipes can be made with [X] and [Y] ingredients?

Answer (score 6):

Try [allrecipes.com](http://allrecipes.com). Ingredients have to be typed, but the results seem relevant.

Example: You are looking for a vegan recipe with avocado and flour, but excludes (veg) butter (I do not know if it makes much sense, but I receive relevant results).

1. Go to ingredient search
2. Type `vegan` in keywords
3. Type `avocado flour` within included textbox
4. Type `butter` within exluded textbox
5. Results page URL should look like this:  `http://allrecipes.com/search/results/?wt=vegan&ingIncl=avocado%20flour&ingExcl=butter&sort=re`, so it is easy to share.

Another option is [Supercook](http://www.supercook.com/#/recipes). It is a recipes search engines. To find recipes using the same filter as above:

1. Type `avocado` and `flour` as key ingredients
2. Type `vegan` in recipe title

The results seem relevant, but I allrecipes.com seems more friendly when it comes to vegan restriction. Also, you cannot exclude an ingredient.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Yummly](http://www.yummly.com/).

By editing taste preferences, once you make an account, you can set your diet to vegan (which is a preset you can choose). This action will set Yummly to only display vegan recipes. You can then search through Yummly with the ingredients you want to use as the parameters.

Answer (score 4):

[Supercook](http://www.supercook.com/#/recipes) is a great option for finding recopies based on defined parameters including ingredients and dietary restrictions.

You're able to add your ingredients, as well as specify vegan, vegetarian, gluten free, etc. and Supercook returns a ton of recipes.  You can type your ingredients or select them from a list of popular items, and recipes that you can make will automatically appear and update.  If you create an account the site will remember what you have on hand and update recipes as you change your ingredients.  That way you can continuously update what ingredients you have.